# Polymorphism does not work with pointers, operator<< overload, inheritance, C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a problem with my code. I have two classes, `A` and `B`, and `B` inherits `A`. I also have operators `<<` overloaded in both classes.

Everything works, I have no compiler errors, but it seems something is wrong. As far as I understand polymorphism, when I use pointers to base class while creating child class with `new`, calling a method should match the child class, not the base class.

For the code below,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    protected:
        int a;

    public:

    A(int aa) : a(aa) {};

    virtual void show(ostream& o) const
    {
        o << "a  = " << a << "\n";
    }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const A &o)
{
    o.show(os);
    return os;
}

class B : public A
{
    private:
        int b;
    public:
        B(int bb, int aa) : A(aa), b(bb){}
        int getb() const {return b;}
};

ostream & operator << ( ostream & os, const B & o)
{
    os << static_cast <const A &>(o);
    os << "\n";
    os << "b = " << o.getb() << "\n";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    A *o1 = new B(2,3);
    cout << *o1;

    cout << "---------------------\n";

    B *o2 = new B(2,3);
    cout << *o2;

    return 0;
}
```

In main:

```
A *o1 = new B(2,3);
cout << *o1;
```

Shows `a = 3`, instead of showing `a = 3 b = 2` (the call should match the child class, not the base class). The thing is, I need to implement the `<<` and `>>` operators in every child class, but I think they do not behave as they should.

The output of the program:

[image]

Even the modified code with re-implmented `show` method shows wrong results, it does not show `a` at all this time:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
    int a;

public:

    A(int aa) : a(aa) {};

    virtual void show(ostream& o) const
    {
        o << "a  = " << a << "\n";
    }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const A &o)
{
    o.show(os);
    return os;
}

class B : public A
{
private:
    int b;
public:
    B(int bb, int aa) : A(aa), b(bb) {}
    int getb() const
    {
        return b;
    }

    void show(ostream& o) const
    {
        o << "b  = " << b << "\n";
    }
};

ostream & operator << ( ostream & os, const B & o)
{
    os << static_cast <const A &>(o);
    o.show(os);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    A *o1 = new B(2,3);
    cout << *o1;

    cout << "---------------------\n";

    B *o2 = new B(2,3);
    cout << *o2;

    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJnvl.png)

Comment: you didn't override `show()` in class B

Comment: You only have to override `show()`. You don't need two overloads of `ostream& operator<<`.

Comment: Your modified code does exactly what you told it to do: it calls `operator <<(ostream&, const A&)` which calls `show` (which calls `B::show` because it's virtual), and then it calls `show` again (which calls `B::show` because it's virtual).

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement the virtual function `show` in derived class B:

```
class B: public A
{
     public:
         // some code here
         virtual void show(ostream& o) const
        {
            o << "b  = " << b << "\n";
        } 
};
```

Comment: Please see my edit in the main post - the result is still wrong.

Comment: A bit of explanation would not go amiss.

Comment: there must be two copies of `show`; one `virtual` in base class and the second in derived class thus the relevant one will be invoked at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

> when I use pointers to base class while creating child class with new,
>   calling a method should match the child class, not the base class

It does when you call a member function ("method" in some other languages), but `operator<<` is not a member function – it's an overloaded free function.
When choosing an overload, only the types known at compile-time are used.

Since `o1` is an `A*`, `*o1` is an `A&`, and the overload for `A&` is chosen.

You're doing this a bit "backwards"; you only need *one* `operator<<`, for the base class, which calls the virtual `show`, and then you override `show` in the derived classes.

Like this:

```
class A
{
    // ...
    virtual void show(ostream& o) const
    {
        o << "a  = " << a << "\n";
    }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const A &o)
{
    o.show(os);
    return os;
}

class B : public A
{
    // ...
    void show(ostream& o) const override
    {
        A::show(o); // Do the "A part".
        o << "b  = " << b << "\n";
    }
};
```

Follow the same pattern for `operator>>`.